# using member in UserControl markup asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to use User Control's member in the asp side.

Here is the c#

```
using DynoPartners.Data;
using System;

namespace DynoPartners.Controls
{
public partial class BusView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
private Business bus;
public Business Bus
{
        get
        {
            return bus;
        }
        set
        {
            bus = value;
        }
}
}
}
```

And the UserControl Code is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BusView.ascx.cs" Inherits="DynoPartners.Controls.BusView" %>
<%= Bus  %>
```

The error message is Error: The name 'Bus' does not exist in the current context

Why is that?

Comment: How are you using the control in aspx page ? and where are you getting the error

Comment: I'm not using it yet in Aspx page. I just started to build it. The word "Bud" is underlined in red. And the error is written in the tooltip.